# How to access Hybris CMS Webservices?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm trying to access cmswebservices with curl with this:

```
curl -u admin:nimda https://localhost:902/cmswebservices/v1/sites -k
```

I'm getting this output:

```
"errors" : [ { "message" : "Access is denied", "type" : "AccessDeniedError" } ] }
```

I hope any Hybris developer can help me to resolve this.

Comment: did you try curl with basic authentication?

Comment: @mkysoft As per curl docs `Without telling which method to use, curl defaults to Basic.`

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or your real port but https is often on 9002 not 902.

Comment: also where did you see that admin credentials should be used? You can try http (9001) and https (9002) the doc is flawed, they mention http protocol with https port...

Comment: @alain.janinm it is not my typo it is my real port. and I  tried with both https 902 and 9002 with https.